# Is it okay to add "transition: all" when in fact you need only one property to transition?

Tags: css

Suppose it's this code:

```
.box {
  width: 200px;
  transition: all .25s linear;
}

.box:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

While I could've used `transition: width`, I used the `all` because it's shorter and does the exact same thing. Is this practice okay from the viewpoint of semantics and meaningful website creation?

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this as it is opinion based.

Comment: But is it meaningfully correct or a bad practice?

Comment: its a common practice, with limited downside.

Comment: If you're asking if it's valid, then the answer is yes. If you're asking about best practices, recommended, commonly done etc., then the question is off-topic.